How to get an event if columns changed?
I use PrimeNG table and also have a selection of columns.
As it is here in an example.
https://primeng.org/table#column-toggle
Now I need to get an event if the colums where changed (afterwards) - for reasons.
How can I get that event?

What do you mean by 'columns were changed'? If you mean re-ordering, then there's an event raised for that, see the docs. If you mean added, then there's no event raised and you'll need to handle that yourself

As you can see in the official repo, these are the only @Output offered by the table.js
There is nothing that notify the changed event inside the columns
/**
 * Emits when the all of the items selected or unselected.
 * @param {TableSelectAllChangeEvent} event - custom  all selection change event.
 * @group Emits
 */
@Output() selectAllChange: EventEmitter<TableSelectAllChangeEvent> = new EventEmitter<TableSelectAllChangeEvent>();
/**
 * Callback to invoke on selection changed.
 * @param {any | null} value - selected data.
 * @group Emits
 */
@Output() selectionChange: EventEmitter<any | null> = new EventEmitter<any | null>();
/**
 * Callback to invoke when a row is selected.
 * @param {TableRowSelectEvent} event - custom select event.
 * @group Emits
 */
@Output() onRowSelect: EventEmitter<TableRowSelectEvent> = new EventEmitter<TableRowSelectEvent>();
/**
 * Callback to invoke when a row is unselected.
 * @param {TableRowUnSelectEvent} event - custom unselect event.
 * @group Emits
 */
@Output() onRowUnselect: EventEmitter<TableRowUnSelectEvent> = new EventEmitter<TableRowUnSelectEvent>();
/**
 * Callback to invoke when pagination occurs.
 * @param {TablePageEvent} event - custom pagination event.
 * @group Emits
 */
@Output() onPage: EventEmitter<TablePageEvent> = new EventEmitter<TablePageEvent>();
/**
 * Callback to invoke when a column gets sorted.
 * @param {Object} object - sort meta.
 * @group Emits
 */
@Output() onSort: EventEmitter<{ multisortmeta: SortMeta[] } | any> = new EventEmitter<{ multisortmeta: SortMeta[] } | any>();
/**
 * Callback to invoke when data is filtered.
 * @param {TableFilterEvent} event - custom filtering event.
 * @group Emits
 */
@Output() onFilter: EventEmitter<TableFilterEvent> = new EventEmitter<TableFilterEvent>();
/**
 * Callback to invoke when paging, sorting or filtering happens in lazy mode.
 * @param {TableLazyLoadEvent} event - custom lazy loading event.
 * @group Emits
 */
@Output() onLazyLoad: EventEmitter<TableLazyLoadEvent> = new EventEmitter<TableLazyLoadEvent>();
/**
 * Callback to invoke when a row is expanded.
 * @param {TableRowExpandEvent} event - custom row expand event.
 * @group Emits
 */
@Output() onRowExpand: EventEmitter<TableRowExpandEvent> = new EventEmitter<TableRowExpandEvent>();
/**
 * Callback to invoke when a row is collapsed.
 * @param {TableRowCollapseEvent} event - custom row collapse event.
 * @group Emits
 */
@Output() onRowCollapse: EventEmitter<TableRowCollapseEvent> = new EventEmitter<TableRowCollapseEvent>();
/**
 * Callback to invoke when a row is selected with right click.
 * @param {TableContextMenuSelectEvent} event - custom context menu select event.
 * @group Emits
 */
@Output() onContextMenuSelect: EventEmitter<TableContextMenuSelectEvent> = new EventEmitter<TableContextMenuSelectEvent>();
/**
 * Callback to invoke when a column is resized.
 * @param {TableColResizeEvent} event - custom column resize event.
 * @group Emits
 */
@Output() onColResize: EventEmitter<TableColResizeEvent> = new EventEmitter<TableColResizeEvent>();
/**
 * Callback to invoke when a column is reordered.
 * @param {TableColumnReorderEvent} event - custom column reorder event.
 * @group Emits
 */
@Output() onColReorder: EventEmitter<TableColumnReorderEvent> = new EventEmitter<TableColumnReorderEvent>();
/**
 * Callback to invoke when a row is reordered.
 * @param {TableRowReorderEvent} event - custom row reorder event.
 * @group Emits
 */
@Output() onRowReorder: EventEmitter<TableRowReorderEvent> = new EventEmitter<TableRowReorderEvent>();
/**
 * Callback to invoke when a cell switches to edit mode.
 * @param {TableEditInitEvent} event - custom edit init event.
 * @group Emits
 */
@Output() onEditInit: EventEmitter<TableEditInitEvent> = new EventEmitter<TableEditInitEvent>();
/**
 * Callback to invoke when cell edit is completed.
 * @param {TableEditCompleteEvent} event - custom edit complete event.
 * @group Emits
 */
@Output() onEditComplete: EventEmitter<TableEditCompleteEvent> = new EventEmitter<TableEditCompleteEvent>();
/**
 * Callback to invoke when cell edit is cancelled with escape key.
 * @param {TableEditCancelEvent} event - custom edit cancel event.
 * @group Emits
 */
@Output() onEditCancel: EventEmitter<TableEditCancelEvent> = new EventEmitter<TableEditCancelEvent>();
/**
 * Callback to invoke when state of header checkbox changes.
 * @param {TableHeaderCheckboxToggleEvent} event - custom header checkbox event.
 * @group Emits
 */
@Output() onHeaderCheckboxToggle: EventEmitter<TableHeaderCheckboxToggleEvent> = new EventEmitter<TableHeaderCheckboxToggleEvent>();
/**
 * A function to implement custom sorting, refer to sorting section for details.
 * @param {any} any - sort meta.
 * @group Emits
 */
@Output() sortFunction: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
/**
 * Callback to invoke on pagination.
 * @param {number} number - first element.
 * @group Emits
 */
@Output() firstChange: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter<number>();
/**
 * Callback to invoke on rows change.
 * @param {number} number - Row count.
 * @group Emits
 */
@Output() rowsChange: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter<number>();
/**
 * Callback to invoke table state is saved.
 * @param {TableState} object - table state.
 * @group Emits
 */
@Output() onStateSave: EventEmitter<TableState> = new EventEmitter<TableState>();
/**
 * Callback to invoke table state is restored.
 * @param {TableState} object - table state.
 * @group Emits
 */
@Output() onStateRestore: EventEmitter<TableState> = new EventEmitter<TableState>();

